# Third Party Tools for Monitoring SQL Server Performance

Tags: sql-server

I'm in a situation where I came into a new job and I have to support several legacy systems.  The original developer is no longer around.  These legacy systems are really hammering away at our SQL Server and killing performance.  I know that there are a lot of things that can be done in the code, but rewriting code is really my last resort.

What I'm looking for is some sort of tool that will monitor the queries coming into the server and give recommendations on indexing solutions.  I know I can use the SQL Server Profiler but I'm looking for something a little more user friendly and something that can help me make the indexing decisions.

I know I didn't explain it very well, but I'm sure this is a common request.  I'd like to make informed decisions on what to index and avoid "shooting from the hip" and indexing everything in sight.  Thanks for any recommendations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a third party tool for this.

Assuming SQL Server 2005+ as long as you can use SQL Profiler (actually SQL Trace - Don't use the Profiler GUI for this to reduce tracing overhead as much as possible) to collect a representative workload you can use the [Database Tuning Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166575.aspx) to automate analysis of the workload and make indexing recommendations.

You can also use the [Missing Index DMVs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2007/07/19/are-you-using-sql-s-missing-index-dmvs.aspx) for a quick overview of areas to investigate but the DTA will do more holistic analysis and take into account possible adverse effects of indexes on data modification statements.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585111/third-party-tools-for-monitoring-sql-server-performance/3585136#3585136), but since you asked about 3rd party tools, I'll mention one of my favorites (and no, I don't work for the company). [Ignite for SQL Server](http://www.confio.com/English/Products/Ignite_for_SQL_Server.php) does an excellent job of analyzing server activity in terms of [wait time analysis](http://redmondmag.com/articles/2009/05/01/sql-speed-secrets.aspx). It won't make recommendations for you, but it will quickly identify the worst performing queries where you need to focus your effort.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005+ has a lot of DMV's (Dynamic Management views) that you can query to get server info, as well as the Profiler / SQL Trace tool.

We administer several large database servers.

Idera is a good tool to manage multiple database servers easily.

I think you'd make a much better DBA if you learn more about the inbuilt functionality of SQL server.

Have a browse of

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754.aspx

to find out more about DMV's and functions.

Another common issue with performance could be your indexes.

Theres a great tutorial that combines the DMV's with improving indexes here:

http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/Using-dynamic-management-views-to-improve-SQL-Server-index-effectiveness

Idera is really worth checking out though as a good starting point. Combined with DMV's & SQL trace there shouldn't be much you won't be able to fix.

Idera just takes most of the leg work out of doing things.

http://www.idera.com/Content/Home.aspx

Idera: SQL Diagnostic Manager

Comment: I'm not planning on becoming a DBA as my current workload won't allow it.  We don't have one, and probably will never have one, so I was trying to find a software package that could pick up some of the slack.

Comment: And "takes most of the leg work out of doing things" is exactly what I'm looking for.  I know I can't automate this completely and I'll still need to use my judgement, but I'm just looking for any shortcut I can.